# What could cause a "smelly sock" smell seeping into our living room from the crawlspace?

Tags: flooring, smell, crawlspace

Our living room floor is wooden so there is a gap between the footings and the floor. In late fall, we get a horrible smell in that room. It smells like smelly socks but worse.

I thought it was because of rain in winter since it seems to start around November or December. It lasts for about a month but then seems to disappear. We do not get it in summer even if we get loads of rain at that time. then so not sure nut really nasty and nothing takes the smell away.

What could be causing the smell at this time, and how can we prevent it?

Comment: I vote to put this on hold as off topic it's more of a house cleaning question. Also by the way the question is worded and punctuated it is kind of hard to understand even exactly what you are asking. The wording and punctuation make it very hard to understand your question please clean up the format and resubmit it in a more specific manner concerning the actual structure of your house and what would be needing to be done to fix it. Also the header on your question is your name which does not pertain to what your question is about.

Comment: @user41750 [tag:cleaning] is on-topic. As for the rest, you can suggest an [edit] if you think a post can be improved.

Comment: @mrsmazturner I edited your post for clarity. I presumed you meant a [crawlspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basement#Crawl_space) by "gap between footings and floor"; please update your post if I was wrong about that.

Answer (score 2):

Access the crawlspace and inspect it with a bright light. Assess for damp areas indicative of water penetration from exterior or from leaky pipe(s). Moisture = mildew/mold which can smell. Use coveralls and a dust mask. Look for any dead critters that could be causing this.

Certain plants and trees drop leaves and stuff that smell (eucalyptus, for example) if left sitting to get damp, ensure accumulated plant matter and debris are raked away from your home.

Whatever issue is found, fix it. Damp nasty soil can often be treated with hydrated lime powder to remove and prevent future odors.